# Python OOP default constructor creation

Tags: python, oop, default-constructor

I am creating a class in Python. I would like to set my variables equal to zero from the start, but I think using "username = none, password = none, url = none" is inefficient. Is there a way for me to instead create a new `def __init__(self):` method that doesn't take any arguments and sets all the attributes to none? This is how it looks currently and thanks for the help!:

```
  Class Broken():
    #pulls from function which is what
    username = none
    password = none
    url = none
    job_url = none
    headers = none
```

and instead, I'd like...

```
def __init__(self):?????
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a fallback `__getattr__` method for that. If the attribute name is in the list, return `None`. In the following example, trying to get the values of a,b or c returns `None` unless they're set.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self,attrname):
       if attrname in {'a','b','c'}:
           return None
       else:
           raise AttributeError(attrname)


f = Foo()
f.a = 23

print(f.a,f.b)
```

prints:

```
23 None
```

Trying to access another unset attribute raises `AttributeError` (the exception message is a bit terse I admit)

Comment: Wouldn't self.__dict__.get('username') be simpler?